# How to feed 10 speakers 10 different signals?

Tags: audio, hardware

How can I output 10 different audio channels to 10 different speakers simultaneously using a Raspberry Pi 3 and its or any other accessories?

I have 10 different mp3 files and I would like to output each file to a different speaker, independent of one another. I don't know what hardware I should use since I can only feed two speakers using my laptop or Raspberry Pi.

Could I use a USB hub (1 USB to 10 USB's) and 10 USB-to-audio adapter? If so, how can I feed them using the Wolfram Language or Python?

Comment: If I am asking this question in the wrong forum, please let me know and I'll move it.

Comment: This is indeed, not a forum. But this is just too broad, I don't think it'd be well received in any Stack Exchange community. Maybe Specify what you mean? What speakers? What are you trying to do? How is it even related to programming?

Comment: Well, its both programming and hardware and the problem is I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Might be best to investigate if a 10 output soundcard you can find is linux compatible and go from there? https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/hardware_support?redirect=1  Then I think it's a separate question about  how to play multi-channel audio from those programming languages.  Also - I thik performance of Python on a Pi might not be adequate for 10 channels of audio.  Maybe you can do it in C++.

Comment: I have kind of the same problem. It seems to be problematic to output at the same time audio on usb soundcard output.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70130320/play-multiple-mp3-files-on-multiple-output-devices-on-raspberry-pi-4)


On the other hand the following link might be handy if you have no problem to use wav files instead of mp3:
https://www.esologic.com/multi-audio/