# Play multiple mp3 files on multiple output devices on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, mp3, soundcard

I need to get 4 - 8 simultaneously playing stereo audio music channels playing continuously mp3 music from specific folders on SD card.

## Working:

- onboard 3,5 audio jack
- usb soundcard playing the music properly

## Problem:

But as soon I’m trying to use the third audio output with an usb soundcard on the raspberry pi than the other soundcard stops working.

**It is only possible to get more than 2 outputs working ☹**

2 sound output are using around 6 % cpu power. And this is the only purpose for these raspberries.
So of course it would be nice and more efficient to get more output from one raspberry.

I tried vlc and mplayer and could address the different usb soundcards without any problems. But its only playing music from one soundcard, no matter what I'm trying.

## Hardware:

- Raspberry Pi 4 b 2 GB
- Tried 6 different USB soundcards with an 3,5 audio jack output

## Other project:

I found this project that did the same with WAV files. But in my case I can't convert all the files to WAV as it needs to stay mp3 files.
https://www.esologic.com/multi-audio/